# Any one know about jQuery UI mouse widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've started working with jQuery UI.

I want to know more about the jQuery UI mouse widget. I'm trying to find out the documentation of it, but it is not available. Any one knows about where the resource is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mouse widget is an internal plugin that seems to be mostly (or only) used for low-level drag-and-drop handling.

I just wrote a blog post about using it to roll your own drag-and-drop (instead of using Draggable): http://www.solitr.com/blog/2012/05/roll-your-own-drag-and-drop-handling-with-jquery-ui/

The gist of it is, you can subclass it, like so:

```
$.widget('ui.custommouse', $.ui.mouse, {
  options: {
    mouseStart: function(e) {},
    mouseDrag: function(e) {},
    mouseStop: function(e) {},
    mouseCapture: function(e) { return true; }
  },
  // Forward events to custom handlers
  _mouseStart: function(e) { return this.options.mouseStart(e); },
  _mouseDrag: function(e) { return this.options.mouseDrag(e); },
  _mouseStop: function(e) { return this.options.mouseStop(e); },
  _mouseCapture: function(e) { return this.options.mouseCapture(e); }
  // Bookkeeping, inspired by Draggable
  widgetEventPrefix: 'custommouse',
  _init: function() {
    return this._mouseInit();
  },
  _create: function() {
    return this.element.addClass('ui-custommouse');
  },
  _destroy: function() {
    this._mouseDestroy();
    return this.element.removeClass('ui-custommouse');
  },
});
```

Then instantiate the `custommouse` plugin you just defined, and pass your own
event handlers as options:

```
$('#containerElement').custommouse({
  mouseStart: function(e) { ... },
  mouseDrag: function(e) { ... },
  mouseStop: function(e) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/ the section titled "Involving the Mouse"

Call this._mouseInit in your own widget's _init function, then overwrite the _mouseDown, _mouseDrag, etc functions.

Answer (score 1):

> New mouse plugin file makes jQuery UI 14% smaller on average
>   The mouse plugin isn’t new, but this release moves it to its own file, jquery.ui.mouse.js, where before it was inside the jQuery UI Core. This means that jQuery UI plugins that don’t depend on the mouse plugin but previously included the jQuery UI Core have less unused code to include, with an average overall file size improvement of 14%. That’s just an average. Some improvements will be as high as 36%.

from [jQuery blog](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/03/jquery-ui-18/) 2010 march

In your jQuery Library (like [this from google](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js)) you can find it as *** jQuery UI Mouse 1.8.11** and more info at [jQuery UI Mouse in the JQs website](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Mouse).